# How can i import a vector in rcpp?

Tags: r, rcpp

Good afternoon ,

I created this **rcpp function** that returns **a 3d matrix** **with** **dimensions K * K * L**.

***Rcpp Code :***

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;   

// [[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector Test( int K , int L ){

  // calling some R functions 

  Function f1("rnorm"); 
  Function f2("runif"); 
  Function f3("ceiling"); 
  Function f4("unique"); 
  Function f5("array"); 
  Function f6("unique.array"); 
  Function f7("print");

  // Creating a vector of normal law with length= K * K * L

  NumericVector rn = f5(f1(K*K*L, Named("sd")=1, _["mean"]=0), Named("dim")=NumericVector::create(K,K,L));

  // Reshaping the 1d vector  , the 3d matrix will be visible in R 
  rn.attr("dim") = Dimension(K, K , L ); 
      return rn ;
    }

***Example of the obtained results :***  The function is called in Rstudio

    > Test(3,2)
    , , 1

            [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.57144807 -0.1650806  0.07607133
[2,]  0.61278268 -0.5049861  0.37705107
[3,]  0.09037529  1.6185765 -0.68675536

, , 2

           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.5789173 -0.6630934  0.9961613
[2,] -0.4425025 -0.9083358 -1.4860523
[3,]  0.2150056 -0.3229108 -1.6536952
```

***My question :***

- Suppose that (K,L)=(3,2) like the example  , how can i **extract in rcpp** the second row / column in the second table of rn (indexed by [ , , 2 ] ) ?
- Is it possible **to store** this extracted vector of length=K in a **numericVector variable** using the **vector.import()** method ?

Sorry but i didn't find an example that could help me !

Thank you a lot !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  If you could, please edit your question to i) remove the extra blank lines as more concise display is better and ii) remove the image and replace it with copy and pasted text.  Thank you.

Comment: @ Dirk Eddelbuettel , i think is difficult to me to remove the picture. I will try to remove the extra blank lines.

Comment: You can mark several lines in any text based terminal, including RStudio, select copy and paste here.  Please conform to the minimal convention to make it easier for us to help you.  I appreciate your understanding in the matter.

Comment: Thank you.  I would also recommend to remove your first and last comment (both are just noise) and to indent the remaining overly long code line so the the complete code is displayed at once. Function f2,f3,f4,f6,f7 are unused, so why not remove them from the code snippet? Remember, _minimally_ complete verifiable examples.  Lastly, you seem to be "writing R code in C++".  Based on my 10+ years experience with Rcpp, not the best way to go about it.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel  , the functions f2 , f3 ... f7 are used. C++ could give me the performance i want. I'm working in a classification project and i prefer to write a part with nested loops in c++.

Comment: No they don't. _They call R functions from C++_ which makes it _slower than R alone_ because you have the overhead of going back and forth. Discussed several times here in other question; try searching for `[rcpp] Function` and whatever clever search trick you can come up with to avoid false positive from C/C++ keyword `function`.  And in any event _they are line noise for your quesiton here_ which is why I suggested to make your question more concise.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel , Ok i understand.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be :

```
NumericVector v1 ; 
NumericVector v2=NumericVector::create(1,2,4,5,6,7,8) ; 
v1= rd.import( v2.begin() , v2.begin()+ 6) ; 
// return elements 1,2,4,5,6,7
```